# How to read the chunking stream using node.js

Tags: node.js, braintree, chunking

The following is the braintree api to search for transaction. The result is received as stream. But Unable to read the received chunks in string or desired format.

```
var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
  result = search.paymentMethodToken().is("h337xg");

});

completeData = ""
stream.on("data", function(chunk){
        // read the chunk
        completeData += chunk;
});
stream.on("end", function(){
    // print the output in console 
    console.log(completeData);
});

stream.resume();
```

The output that can be seen in the console is as : 
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: Did you try console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk)) ? It might be a JSON and not a string

Answer (score 2):

(I work at Braintree)

The data that's returned is a JSON object. In order to concatenate all the responses together, you'll need to have something like this:

`completeData += JSON.stringify(chunk);`

If you have any further questions on this, feel free to email our support team at support@braintreepayments.com